# Machine to Machine Authorization with IdentityServer4

Tags: asp.net-identity, identityserver4

I have a client integration and I wanted a Machine to Machine authorization between there server and our servers. I assumed that I could use the authorization_code flow but it seems like it needs the user cookie to be present otherwise it always redirects to the login page.

Is there a way using IdentityServer4 that a server can request me with some user information e.g. maybe an encrypted user identifier and I can use that to return an authorization code? I have been able to achieve some of this with my own implementation of the `AuthorizeInteractionResponseGenerator`. I override the `ProcessLoginAsync()` method and introduced a new prompt type lets say `abc` so when the provided prompt type is `abc`, I take user's identifiers from the raw request and log that user in generating a `ClaimsPrincipal` until in the end I get the error:

> InvalidOperationException: User is not currently authenticated

Stack trace presented is something as follows:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: User is not currently authenticated
   at IdentityServer4.Services.DefaultUserSession.<SetClientListPropertyValueAsync>d__26.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at IdentityServer4.Services.DefaultUserSession.<SetClientsAsync>d__25.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at IdentityServer4.Services.DefaultUserSession.<AddClientIdAsync>d__22.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at IdentityServer4.Endpoints.Results.AuthorizeResult.<ProcessResponseAsync>d__12.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at IdentityServer4.Endpoints.Results.AuthorizeResult.<ExecuteAsync>d__10.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at IdentityServer4.Hosting.IdentityServerMiddleware.<Invoke>d__3.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at IdentityServer4.Hosting.IdentityServerMiddleware.<Invoke>d__3.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.<Invoke>d__6.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Cors.Infrastructure.CorsMiddleware.<Invoke>d__8.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at IdentityServer4.Hosting.BaseUrlMiddleware.<Invoke>d__3.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles.StaticFileMiddleware.<Invoke>d__7.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult()
   at Rp.Middleware.IdHashing.IdHashingMiddleware.<Invoke>d__7.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.<Invoke>d__7.MoveNext()
```

This has to be done because of a requirement, there is no debate on that but what I'd like your help on is that how can I resolve the above mentioned error? Moreover, am I doing too much re-work whereas I could leverage IdentityServer4 in some other way to achieve this?

Looking forward to your response. Thanks!

**Update:**

So to give everyone a little more context, I am not trying to do a Single Signon. What I am doing is that I am building a application for a client who doesn't want the users to know that the application is not from them. So the user logs into the client website but on one of the pages, out Angular application loads. Now this application doesn't rely on the client, it has everything it needs in our DB, all it needs from the client is some thing to pass us so that we can login the client user on our app as well but without any consent or anything to give a feeling that our app is actually part of the client app. And we can't completely rely on the client auth either because I have multiple clients and everyone does auth differently.

Comment: It is still unclear. How will you authenticate users to your app? And how will your clients send you that “thing”?

Comment: What I had in mind was, a client when authenticating the user on there side can get the auth code and put in the cookie. Whenever our Angular app is activated, it picks the auth code, gets access and refresh tokens and starts working.

Comment: That is as insecure as it gets. You should look at different design options. Also will you even be able to access cookie info since client app i would imagine would be on a different domain.

Comment: I don't understand how is that insecure? Our domains will be the same so I can access the cookie. Everything is over HTTPS so I see no way that a man-in-the-middle could be intercepting the auth_code or access/refresh tokens. So, unless the hacker has access to the users machine, I don't see a way this is insecure. Can you please shed some light on why you think it is insecure?

Comment: For starter, SPA's have limited options when it comes to storing refresh tokens which are quite more powerful than short lived access tokens. Also you will be circumventing what the OAuth2 protocol because you will have two web apps (one owned by you and one owned by your client) to share the tokens/auth codes so they will be acting as one client when they should in fact be 2. Having said that, if you host everything on same domain, then I think what you are proposing is possible to hack together though and as you mentioned it will be relatively seucre because of https and such.

Comment: Yes, I understand the power of refresh tokens which is why we are storing them in session storage so that as soon as a browser is closed, they are lost!

Comment: About SPA and storage, please read https://leastprivilege.com/2019/01/18/an-alternative-way-to-secure-spas-with-asp-net-core-openid-connect-oauth-2-0-and-proxykit/ and linked articles.

Answer (score 3):

The flow that is preferred for machine to machine communication is called `client credentials`. Having said that, it looks like you need to have user context in your machine to machine communication scenario so you could also technically use `resource owner credentials` flow. In order to do so, you will need to implement `IResourceOwnerPasswordValidator` on identity server 4 side.

Before you embark on any of these implementations, please make sure you understand the security concerns of using `resource owner credentials` flow as it is generally frowned upon and not recommended. Also it appears that you are looking for user context to be present in your machine to machine communication scenario so that already seems like a red flag in the design.

If you need more info, you can refer to the excellent quickstart samples for identity server 4 where you can check how both of the aforementioned flows can be implemented.

[Identity Server 4 samples](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4.Samples)

Comment: I have updated the original post. Please check, Thanks! :-)